# How to lemmatise a dataframe column Python

Tags: python, dataframe, lemmatization

How can lemmatise a dataframe column. CSV file "train.csv" looks like this

```
id  tweet
1   retweet if you agree
2   happy birthday your majesty
3   essential oils are not made of chemicals
```

I performed the following

```
import pandas as pd
from nltk.tokenize import TweetTokenizer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer

train_data = pd.read_csv('train.csv', error_bad_lines=False)
print(train_data)

# Removing stop words
stop = stopwords.words('english')
test = pd.DataFrame(train_data['tweet'])
test.columns = ['tweet']

test['tweet_without_stopwords'] = test['tweet'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([word for word in x.split() if word not in (stop)]))
print(test['tweet_without_stopwords'])

# TOKENIZATION
tt = TweetTokenizer()
test['tokenised_tweet'] = test['tweet_without_stopwords'].apply(tt.tokenize)
print(test)
```

output:

```
0 retweet if you agree ... [retweet, agree]
1 happy birthday your majesty ... [happy, birthday, majesty]
2 essential oils are not made of chemicals ... [essential, oils, made, chemicals]
```

I tried the following to lemmatise but I'm getting this error *TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'*

```
lmtzr = WordNetLemmatizer()
lemmatized = [[lmtzr.lemmatize(word) for word in test['tokenised_tweet']]]
print(lemmatized)
```

Comment: it seems test is a list, so you can't call test['tokenised_tweet'],  I think you need to give more details of your code... what is test?

Comment: Is it? test = pd.DataFrame(train_data['tweet'])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do the calculation on the dataframe itself:

changing:

```
lmtzr = WordNetLemmatizer()
lemmatized = [[lmtzr.lemmatize(word) for word in test['tokenised_tweet']]]
print(lemmatized)
```

```
lmtzr = WordNetLemmatizer()
test['lemmatize'] = test['tokenised_tweet'].apply(
                    lambda lst:[lmtzr.lemmatize(word) for word in lst])
```

full code:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
data=StringIO(
"""id;tweet
1;retweet if you agree
2;happy birthday your majesty
3;essential oils are not made of chemicals"""
)
test = pd.read_csv(data,sep=";")

import pandas as pd
from nltk.tokenize import TweetTokenizer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer

# Removing stop words
stop = stopwords.words('english')

test['tweet_without_stopwords'] = test['tweet'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([word for word in x.split() if word not in (stop)]))
print(test['tweet_without_stopwords'])

# TOKENIZATION
tt = TweetTokenizer()
test['tokenised_tweet'] = test['tweet_without_stopwords'].apply(tt.tokenize)
print(test)

lmtzr = WordNetLemmatizer()
test['lemmatize'] = test['tokenised_tweet'].apply(
                    lambda lst:[lmtzr.lemmatize(word) for word in lst])
print(test['lemmatize'])
```

output

```
0                    [retweet, agree]
1          [happy, birthday, majesty]
2    [essential, oil, made, chemical]
Name: lemmatize, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for future reference, not to revive an old thread.

Here is how I have done it, it could be improved but it works:

```
w_tokenizer = nltk.tokenize.WhitespaceTokenizer()
lemmatizer = nltk.stem.WordNetLemmatizer()
def lemmatize_text(text):
    return [lemmatizer.lemmatize(w) for w in w_tokenizer.tokenize(text)]

df['Summary'] = df['Summary'].apply(lemmatize_text)
df['Summary'] = df['Summary'].apply(lambda x : " ".join(x))
```

'''

Change the names of the DF columns to your choosings, basically this tokenizes each of the texts, lemmatizes them, and rejoins them once finished.